# JQuery get position of the clicked button in a gridview

Tags: jquery, gridview

I'm quite new to JQuery, made some progress but now in a corner, so would greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

I have an asp.net gridview (within an update panel) which can contain any number of rows. On each row I have a couple of databound labels showing a product price and code, also on the row I have an imagebutton. What I'm trying to do is when the button is clicked to display some of the row data in a faded in Div to the right of the button. So that a user is informed of an item being added to a cart for example.

I've got as far as reading the row data and fading in the div with the row information. But struggling to get the clicked buttons position so I can reposition the Div next to the appropriate button.

Here's some code:

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
{ 
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Item"), new DataColumn("Price"),   new     DataColumn("Code") }); 
    dt.Rows.Add("Shirt", 200, "abc"); 
    dt.Rows.Add("Football", 30, "xyz"); 
    dt.Rows.Add("Bat", 22.5, "sym"); 
    GridView1.DataSource = dt; 
    GridView1.DataBind(); 
}
```

}

Markup: I've removed the update panel, to reduce the code size.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad() {
        $("[id*=lnkSelect]").live("click", function () {

            //Get the values
            var code = $("#code").html($(".code", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
            var price = $("#price").html($(".price", $(this).closest("tr")).html());

            //Build the new HTML
            $(code).prepend("<br/>Item: ");
            $(code).append("<br/>Has been<br/>added to your cart.");
            $(code).append("<br/>Price: ");
            $(code).append(price);
            $(".tooltipleft").html(code); //Set the new HTML
            $(".tooltipleft").fadeIn("slow").fadeOut("slow"); //Show the div

            return true;
        });

    };
</script>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Item"/>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" ForeColor="DimGray" CssClass="price" Text='<%# Eval( "Price") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCode" runat="server" ForeColor="DimGray" CssClass="code" Text='<%# Eval( "Code") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Buttons/add_to_cart.png"
                            AlternateText="Add To Cart" ImageAlign="Right" CssClass="buttontag" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    <div class="tooltipleft" id="tooltip">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Would appreciate any help.

Cheers

CM

Answer (score 0):

This should put you on the right track:

**EDIT**
To reflect my jsfiddle in the comments

```
         $("[id*=lnkSelect]").live("click", function () {
             var pos=$("#imgBut1").offset();
             $("#divinquestion").css({"position": "absolute", "display" : "block" }).show().offset({top:pos.top,left:pos.left+35});

          });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this as well as offset and unfortunately the div always fades in and out in excatly the same location. Is it something to do with the update panel? I've litterally spend days on this and its driving me insane.

Comment: Yeah so irritating getting stuck on something. Had it recently. Try this:    [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjay225/c9TyZ/)

Comment: Hi jjay25, cheers for the help, but just about to concede defeat on this one. I removed the update panel and the div didn't even show at all. So will probably just get the div to show in the top right of the browser window.

Comment: You're welcome man. Sorry you couldn't get it working. It could be a question of z-indexes that the div is not showing. You made sure the div styling is as I had it on the example above.It could be the issue of needing "!important" on your styles for the div if you have clashes with other classes. Have you tried using firebug/chrome developer tools and edit the html through the browser to see what you can come up with? That always helps me to see whats going on. Anyway good luck!